# How to write and read json or txt files spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create a simple manual Caching system in my server by using Spring Boot.
To succeed it, I wrote two different files, one of it for caching time and other one is the data. I planned to write at first request and other requests in 5 minutes will call from file.

The problem is the flow working correctly in my localhost but when I deploy my code, spring boot can not create a new file and read it of course.

The codes are my writing and reading like below.

```
 @Override
public void writeFile( String folder, String path, String data ) throws IOException {
    File file = new File( folder );
    if ( !file.exists() ) {
        if ( file.mkdir() ) {
            System.out.println( "Directory is created!" );
        } else {
            System.out.println( "Failed to create directory!" );
        }
    }

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( path ) );
    writer.write( data );

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

@Override
public String readFile( File file ) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
        String text;

        while ( ( text = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
            buffer.append( text );
        }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if ( reader != null ) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

When I call write file method in Localhost, it is creating the necessary files and folders. In the picture below, it is creating lastsavedtime.txt and readerlist.json.

[image: the files created by method]

And readFile method reads the files successfully.
The same process not working on server.

Spring Boot version : 2.0.5.RELEASE
Azure Web App as server.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is there any error/exception message?

Comment: What is the file path to which you are writing? IMHO caching shouldn't happen in a file. Caching should happen in-memory. And if you really want to write data to a file, then the file should be in resources folder.

Comment: I tried on my side and I assume it may relate to file path, if so, you can try to use absolute path like 'File file = new File("src/main/resources/templates/testfile")' and 'BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "src/main/resources/templates/testfile/cout.txt" ) );'

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar As I said it is a manual caching method, I will storage many temporary file in my folder. I tried with resources folder as well but I will try carefully again.

Comment: @Tiny-wa Thank you for suggesting. Actually I tried to write/read in resources but I will try again carefully.

Comment: I am sorry It doesnt work. The problem continues @Tiny-wa

Comment: Cloud you pls show us a example of the enter parameter of 'writeFile', what's the folder, path in localhost and in server?

Comment: I've tried in my place and by adding "try catch" I found the exception comes from folder, for instance, in my localhost, I can use src/.../xx.txt, but after deploying, I used kudu and found that in '\home\site\wwwroot' only exists an 'app.jar', so the program can't create folder and file. Then I tried to change the folder like 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/testfile/cout.txt', then it worked. By the way, it's better to use 'file.mkdirs()' to create folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supplementary notes about the comment.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newFile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newFile(String folder, String path, String data){     
//      File file = new File("D:/home/site/wwwroot/testfile");      
        File file = new File( folder );
        file.mkdirs();
        try {
//          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("D:/home/site/wwwroot/testfile/cout.txt") );
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( path ) );    
            writer.write( data );       
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return "hello world";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: /home/site/wwwroot path worked! Thank you very much :D